# Vertices that don't belong to vertex group move in pose mode

Tags: armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I've been trying to rig a fox-shaped mesh in Blender for quite some time now and keep on failing to move legs independently. Although i carfully weight-painted the mesh after using *with automatic weigthpaint*, moving one leg always leads to movement of vertices that are not at all weigthpainted. I would be so grateful for any piece of advice!

[image]

A couple of Vertices is moving back and forth in accordance with the pposite leg without beening weight-painted. Espacially those in the red circle.
I have been looking at it in vertex selection masking as well and i'm sure there's no accidental weight on the right legt

[image]

[This is a link to the .blend file in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qb19y6t75gqowj/Fuchs-Rig-3.1.blend?dl=0)

Thanks for looking into this in Advance!!

Comment: Hey Denis I see how these problems look alike, but I can't find any accidental weight on the leg, i've been looking for it for ages. It would be great if you would mind having a second look at it.

Comment: You have exactly the same problem as the duplicate question, Unterarm R and Unterarm L have very low value weights all over the mesh.

Comment: Ah Ok. Now i see what you mean. Sorry it tok me so long to find the weight-painting.